# System files using 21 GB of space?

Tags: 8.1, storage, lumia-icon

On my Verizon Lumia Icon (929), the "System" files are taking up 21.23 GB of my 32 GB of fixed space (doesn't support a micro sd card). Everything I've read indicates that System files should take up no more than 5 GB. The phone runs Windows 8.1 Denim. Any help?

Comment: I recommend you do a factory reset: `Settings>About>Reset your phone`.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a peculiar behavior from which I can only assume there's a glitch. The only solution I can think of is hard resetting your phone.

1. Make a backup of everything you need (photos etc) before starting.
2. Download the [Windows Recovery Tool](http://download-fds.webapps.microsoft.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/WindowsPhoneRecoveryToolInstaller.exe) to your computer.
3. Connect your Windows Phone to the PC with the USB Cable. If your phone is not automatically detected, disconnect it from your computer and press ‘My phone was not detected’ at the bottom and follow the instructions on the screen.
4. After the phone is detected, tap the phone model on the screen to continue.
5. The next screen shows the available software versions. Tap the reinstall button at the bottom
6. There’s a disclaimer that suggests backing up your phone. Tap continue at the bottom.
7. The recovery tool downloads and installs the firmware. This may take a while depending on your network connection. The installation files are about 1.7 GB. Make sure not to disconnect the cable.
8. If all goes well, you get a message that says, “Operation successfully completed.”

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to the problem [here](https://forums.windowscentral.com/showthread.php?t=403676&p=3361395&viewfull=1#post3361395).

In short, some apps are actually taking up the space, but showing it as System & reserved. If you go to the Apps & games section of the storage app and scroll through  your list of apps/games, you should be able to see the break down of which apps are taking up the space.

In my case, it was Deezer with (10GB) and Instagram with (7GB). In the storage app System & reserved was showing as 24,3GB, and Apps & games only 1,61GB.

I just copied the responsible apps to my SD card, and all was well again.

The best part about this solution is you don't need to hard reset your phone.